# How to add mouse-over pause in Tiny Carousel

Tags: jquery

I want to make [Tiny Carousel](http://baijs.com/tinycarousel/) stop on mouseover. 
but there is no pause function described in the javascript

Comment: That plugin does not seem to have a pause function. If you need that functionality I'd suggest you use a different carousel plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$("#slider").tinycarousel({ interval: true });

    var slider = $("#slider").data("plugin_tinycarousel");
    $("#slider").on('mouseover',function(){
      slider.stop();
    })
```

Comment: This fixed my problem, Thank you very much for taking the time to answer. thanks madalin